# Moving spinner items in a Bundle from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to get the value from a Spinner on my android application and convert it into a String so I can move it over as a data item in a Bundle to another activity. I have successfully managed to move EditText values over using the combination of `getText().toString();` methods. I'm looking for the same result but with Spinner items now but have so far had no success.

Here's the code:

This method is called when a user selects a button in the `onClick` method:

```
public void commitData(){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", txtBuildingName.getText().toString()); //Gets the TEXT that the TEXTVIEW was holding converts it to a String and adds to the Extras bundle

    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
    bundle1.putString("key1", txtDescription.getText().toString()); // Same again

    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
    bundle2.putString("key2", type.getItemAtPosition(type.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());

    Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
    bundle3.putString("key3", project.getItemAtPosition(project.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), DataSummary.class);
    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    newIntent.putExtras(bundle1);
    startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
}
```

I am getting no results from the project and type lines of code using `type.getItemAtPosition().getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();` and the same for project.

Shown below is the code for the Activity that receives and output this data from the entry form.

TextView resultName; 
    TextView resultDescription;
    TextView resultType;
    TextView resultProject;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_summary);

   //Check if there is anything in the 'bundle' and if not produce message - AVOIDS NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION when navigating to Activity
   Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();     
   if (bundle != null){       
   String name = bundle.getString("key");
   String description = bundle.getString("key1"); //gets data from DataEntry activity
   String type = bundle.getString("key2");
   String project = bundle.getString("key3");

   resultName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultName);  //adds the TextViews to the activity
   resultType=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultType);
   resultDescription=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultDesc);
   resultProject=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultProject);

   resultName.setText(name); // Fills the textviews with imported data
   resultType.setText(type);
   resultDescription.setText(description);
   resultProject.setText(project);
   }    

   else
   {
       Toast.makeText(DataSummary.this,"Received no data yet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

}
```

Anyone got any ideas how to successfully gather the data from the Spinner item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you passing different bundles? On the side of your receiving Activity you are only getting the first bundle, I guess.

Try your code with these edits:

```
public void commitData(){

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", txtBuildingName.getText().toString()); //Gets the TEXT that the TEXTVIEW was holding converts it to a String and adds to the Extras bundle
    bundle.putString("key1", txtDescription.getText().toString()); // Same again
    bundle.putString("key2", type.getItemAtPosition(type.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());
    bundle.putString("key3", project.getItemAtPosition(project.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());
```

Comment: ahh yes thank you! I figured it out first with separate bundles, I wasn't putting them into extras. But using just one bundle will save on complexity and code duplication. Thank you for you help, much appreciated :)

Comment: Could possibly edit the code to accommodate putting an image in the Bundle as well? I need to be able to move over a picture of the building in question onto the next Activity... tried using `byte[]` variable but getting a little lost!

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question so that all SO users can benefit from it.

Comment: It's okay I figured it out :)